# Convert html to pdf file with php

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I need to convert the html receipt to pdf file. in html file I also have php information. 
How can I provide such a thing? 
could you suggest me with codes.

Comment: Surely this question has been asked before here? Check the _Related_ section on the right.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a listing question, but we've used DOMPDF as @skippy suggested, and rejected it because it is a REAL troublemaker when tables surpass a page.

We've moved to http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ , which is -in my opinion- way better. It's being used in a production environment sending out lots of pdfs per day. It uses the webkit rendering enginge (you know, the one that chrome uses) and is therefore awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) project ? It simply rockz...

If that is not enough, you may want to browse StackOverflow itself :

[Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to automagically convert html to pdf:

[www.tcpdf.org](http://www.tcpdf.org)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

My company has a product called DocRaptor that converts HTML to PDF using an HTTP POST request.

DocRaptor is built using Prince, and produces higher quality results than similar programs.

Here's a link to DocRaptor's homepage:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code there is no need to  installation of any thing .
[http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/)/